# Applying Commutivity Law to a Tautology $P\lor \neg (P \land Q) $

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

How do I apply Commutivity law to a tautology: $P\lor \neg(P \land Q)$?

I understand the it is $A\lor B = B\lor A$, but how can this apply to the above tautology?

Do I assume $P$ as $A$, and $\neg (P\land Q)$ as $B$?

---

I just checked the answer, the answer is: $\neg Q \lor \top$. Where did the $\top$ come from?

Comment: It depends if you mean commutativity with respect to $\lor$ or with respect to $\land$.

Comment: Distribute $\neg$ over $P\land Q$ to find $\top$.

Comment: Do you mean `P∧~P` instead? `P∨~(P∧Q) = P∨~P∨~Q`, then replace `P∨~P` with T?

Comment: No, the only four possible commutations (there are infinite possibilities, but all of them yield one of these four) are $P\lor \neg (P\land Q), \, P\lor \neg (Q\land P), \, \neg (P\land Q)\lor P, \, \neg(Q\land P)\lor P$. The answer to the second question in your comment is yes.

Comment: I see you're a new user. Please read about accepting answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) and [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Comment: "Do I assume P as A, and ~(P∧Q) as B?"  Yes, you can do that.  "I just checked the answer, the answer is ~Q ∨ T. Where did the T come from??"  (P $\lor$ ~P)=T.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *don't* simplify the statement using commutativity.

Take the statement:
$$P \lor \neg (P \land Q)$$
Apply DeMorgan's Laws: The negation of a conjunction is the disjunction of the negations.
$$= P\lor (\neg P \lor \neg Q)$$
Disjunctions are associative.
$$= (P\lor \neg P)\lor \neg Q$$
The disjunction of a preposition and its negation is a tautology.
$$= {\large\top}\lor \neg Q$$
The disjunction of a tautology and a preposition is a tautology.
$$= {\large\top}$$

Comment: Does this mean we'll always need to apply DeMorgan's law first then only I can do communtativity and identity law?

Comment: @user3650172 It's *associativity*; but yes, a negation of something in brackets is a strong indication that DeMorgan's Laws will be needed.